# Show message on empty table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new in Angular. I implemented  material table where I load data from service and call in component like this:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.UsuariosService.getUser().subscribe(results => {
      if (!results) {
        return;
      }
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

    });
  }
```

It works correctly, but now I want to show message when table is empty so I try:

HTML:

```
<mat-table>
    //content there
</mat-table>
  <div *ngIf="noResults$ | async"> No results</div>
```

then in component something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.UsuariosService.getUser().subscribe(results => {
      if (!results) {
        return;
      }
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      var noResults$ = results.map(d => d.length === 0).startWith(false);

    });
  }
```

But I get 3 errors:

Error 1 (Html):

> Identifier 'noResults$' is not defined. The component declaration,
>   template variable declarations, and element references do not contain
>   such a member

I dont know why, because I declare noResults$ on component

Error 2 (Component):

> message: 'Property 'length' does not exist on type 'User'.'

Why 'length' search for property? Is supposed length is a method who looking for register in service

Error 3 (Component):

> Property 'startWith' does not exist on type 'boolean[]'.

I don't know nothing about this error

Help is very appreciated. Regards

Complete component:

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit,
  ViewEncapsulation,
  ViewChild,
  ElementRef
} from "@angular/core";
import { ModalDismissReasons, NgbDateStruct } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { ScriptLoaderService } from "../../../../../_services/script-loader.service";
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";

import { UsuariosService } from "../../../../../_services/usuarios.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import {
  DataSource,
  CollectionViewer,
  SelectionModel
} from "@angular/cdk/collections";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";
import {
  MatSort,
  MatSortable,
  MatTableDataSource,
  MatPaginator,
  MatPaginatorIntl
} from "@angular/material";


import { SwalComponent } from "@toverux/ngx-sweetalert2";

@Component({
  selector: "usuarios",
  templateUrl: "./usuarios.component.html",
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class UsuariosComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild("filter") filter: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild("deleteSwal") private deleteSwal: SwalComponent;

  // Bootstrap switch
  public yes: string = "SI";
  public no: string = "NO";
  public green: string = "green";
  public gray: string = "gray";
  public disabled: boolean = false;
  public status: boolean = false;
  public normal: string = "small";
  //end Bootstrap switch

  public eliminar: string = "ELIMINAR";
  public cancelar: string = "CANCELAR";
  public red: string = "red";


  selection = new SelectionModel<string>(true, []);
  dataSource;

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  displayedColumns = [
    "id",
    "nombre",
    "apellido",
    "email",
    "perfil",
    "ultimoLogin",
    "activo",
    "action"
  ];

  constructor(
    private _script: ScriptLoaderService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private UsuariosService: UsuariosService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.UsuariosService.getUser().subscribe(results => {
      if (!results) {
        return;
      }
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      var noResults$ = results.map(d => d.length === 0).startWith(false);

    });
  }

  onFlagChange(event, { id }) {
    const body: any = {
      usuarioId: id,
      activo: event
    };
    this.UsuariosService.postSwitch(body).subscribe(
      () => {
        //React to your HTTP request success
        this.toastr.success("El Usuario se ha actualizado correctamente.");
      },
      err => {
        this.toastr.error("Ocurrió un error al actualizar Usuario.");
        //React to your HTTP request error
      }
    );
  }
  deleteUser(userid) {
    debugger;
    this.UsuariosService.eliminar(userid).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.toastr.success("El usuario se ha eliminado con éxito.");
      },
      err => {
        this.toastr.error("Ocurrió un error al eliminar Usuario.");
      }
    );
  }
}
```

**Update**

First problem solved adding `noResults$` as  `public noResults$: any;`

and call in method as simple as:

```
this.noResults$ = results.map(d => d.length === 0).startWith(false);
```

Comment: You're creating `noResults$` as a local variable-- it is only visible within `ngOnInit`. You need to change it to `public noResults$`, and set it with `this.noResults$ = `

Comment: Yes, first problem solved. Thankyou @user184994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function is used to transform each item within an array.

When you do:

```
results.map(d => d.length === 0).startWith(false);
```

That is trying to check the `length` property of each user. Finally, it is then trying to use `startWith` on the new array, but arrays don't have a `startWith` function.

Assuming you just want to check if the array is empty, you can do:

```
this.noResults = d.length === 0;
```

*Note that I haven't used `noResults$` as the variable name. The name should only end in `$` if it is an Observable, but in this case it is not.*

Comment: I do it as:  `this.noResults = results.length === 0;` as you say, and I debbug it, it comes with length 0. It pass without errors but no message appear.

Comment: You don't need the `async` pipe in the HTML either because it's not an Observable. It should just be `<div *ngIf="noResults"> No results</div>`

Answer (score 0):

1) The HTML is looking for the variable `noResults$` before it is being rendered by the `OnInit` hook.
You need to define it before the component renders (before the constructor) and reference it within the `OnInit` function like so

```
ngOnInit() {
this.UsuariosService.getUser().subscribe(results => {
  if (!results) {
    return;
  }
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.noResults$ = results.map(d => d.length === 0).startWith(false);

  });
}
```

2 & 3) You should not need to map through the response if you are using the Angular HTTPClient to make the get Request, that could be causing both these errors. You should run the following to test to see what is being assigned to `d`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.UsuariosService.getUser().subscribe(results => {
    if (!results) {
      return;
    }
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    console.log(results)
    this.noResults$ = results.map(d => {
      console.log(d)
   }).startWith(false);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set `else` for `ngIf` and set template what will be rendered it this case.

```
<mat-table *ngIf="dataSource.data; else placeholder">
    //content there
</mat-table>
<ng-template #placeholder>
   <div> No results</div> 
</ng-template>
```

more info you can find here https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-else-then#ngif-and-else